# Python: Convert 8 byte IEEE754 number to float

Tags: python, floating-point, binary, type-conversion

I have the following 8 byte string that forms part of a binary file

```
b = b'?\xf0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

and I want to convert it to a floating point number (which should be equal to 7.371791007870371e+05).  None of the approaches that I've tried so far have worked:

- literal_eval

  from ast import literal_eval
  literal_eval(b)
  ValueError: malformed node or string: b'?\xf0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
- following @martineau's answer in this post: [How to convert a binary (string) into a float value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751653/how-to-convert-a-binary-string-into-a-float-value)

  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: b'?\xf0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

In both cases the errors raised suggest that the string 'b' is invalid, but I don't see how this is possible as it's read straight from the binary file.

Comment: Your string `b` is likely invalid (it's all null bytes except the first 2) - at the very least, that string does not represent the float 7.371791007870371e+05.

Comment: btw 8 bytes float for the number in your question should look like `b'\xc8[\x9a36\x7f&A'`.

Comment: `struct.unpack('d', b'\xc8[\x9a36\x7f&A')[0]` should work then. Output is `737179.100787037`

Comment: `float` takes 4 bytes. Which of your 8 bytes you want to convert?

Answer (score 2):

This should unpack the bytes to a double (8 bytes, not a float which is 4 bytes). Note that I use the value from @wim.

```
import struct
print(struct.unpack('d', b'\xc8[\x9a36\x7f&A')[0])
```