# Discrepancy of floating representation

Tags: python, floating-point, floating-accuracy

In [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8762541/1011859), an user provided this short function that returns the binary representation of a floating-point value:

```
import struct
import sys

def float_to_bin(f):
    """ Convert a float into a binary string. """
    if sys.version_info >= (3,):  # Python 3?
        ba = struct.pack('>d', f)
    else:
        ba = bytearray(struct.pack('>d', f)) # Convert str result.

    s = ''.join('{:08b}'.format(b) for b in ba)
    return s[:-1].lstrip('0') + s[0] # Strip but one leading zero.
```

When I call this function with the value `7/3-4/3` (in Python 3.5), or with `1.0000000000000002`, I get this binary representation :

`11111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Using [this online tool](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=049046048048048048048048048048048048048048048048048050), with the same values, I get this binary representation :

`11111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001`

- Why is there a difference between these two representations ?
- Why is `float_to_bin` returning the floating representation of `1.0` for `1.0000000000000002` ?
- Is there some precision loss in `float_to_bin` induced somewhere (maybe when calling `struct.pack`) ?

Comment: `1.0000000000000002` isn't the precise value of a floating point number, so different implementations may parse it differently.

Comment: A float is only 32 bits, the rest of the bits are significant digits.

Comment: Did you see this at the web site? `Most accurate representation = 1.00000000000000022204460492503E0`

Comment: @APorter1031 `float` values in Python are double-precision (64-bit) floating point, not single-precision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic in that function to "strip but one leading zero" is completely wrong, and is removing significant digits from the result.

The correct representation of the value is *neither* of the values mentioned in your question; it is:

```
0011111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

which can be retrieved by replacing the last line of that function with:

```
return s
```

or by using the simpler implementation:

```
def float_to_bin(f):
    [d] = struct.unpack(">Q", struct.pack(">d", f))
    return '{:064b}'.format(d)
```

Leading and trailing zeroes in floating-point values are significant, and cannot be removed without altering the value.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format for a more in depth explanation

Comment: @duskwuff : Thank you. That explains it. I should have looked more thoroughly at the provided code.