# How do I convert a string of a floating point decimal number into a float type?

Tags: python, casting

I have a 32bit floating point decimal in sting format. I want to get it into float format.

For exmaple, how do I convert this string: '01000010000000001110111010011000'
into this float: 32.233001709

Perhaps there is some intermediate step where the string is converted into binary: 0b01000010000000001110111010011000?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a binary (string) into a float value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751653/how-to-convert-a-binary-string-into-a-float-value)

Comment: You may find your answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751653/how-to-convert-a-binary-string-into-a-float-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapting my answer from one of the questions posted as a possible duplicate:

```
s2 = '01000010000000001110111010011000'
struct.unpack('f', struct.pack('I', int(s2, 2)))[0]
```

It's a three-step process.  First convert the binary string to `int`.  Second convert that to a sequence of bytes.  Third convert those bytes to `float`.