# How to print out double from binary format in python

Tags: python, binary

```
import struct
fileContent = b'@X\xa6fffff\x00\x00\x03\xe8\x01'
d = struct.unpack('d', fileContent[:8])
print(d)  # prints 98.6
```

I tried to use the struct module's unpack function but it returns large number `1.9035985675205313e+185` instead of `98.6` which it is supposed to do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a binary (string) into a float value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751653/how-to-convert-a-binary-string-into-a-float-value)

Comment: struct.pack('d', 98.6) gives me b'fffff\xa6X@'.  System byte order on the file io maybe? No, that wouldn't reverse all the bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: struct - Interpret strings as packed binary data](https://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#module-struct).

If the expected value out of (the beginning of) this contents is ***98.6***, @KennyOstrom's comment is correct, it's the byte order (buffer is encoded using ***big** endian*, while the default (for *Intel* / *AMD* processors - *pc064*) is *little endian*)).
I prepared a small example (used *unpack_from* as it offers more flexibility).

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import struct
import sys


def main(*argv):
    buf = b"@X\xa6fffff\x00\x00\x03\xe8\x01"

    for fmt, desc in (
        ("d", "default"),
        ("<d", "little"),
        (">d", "big"),
        ("@d", "native"),
    ):
        print("{:s}: {:.3f}".format(desc, struct.unpack_from(fmt, buf, offset=0)[0]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> (py_pc064_03.10_test1_pycoral) [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackExchange/StackOverflow/q075636237]> python code00.py 
> Python 3.10.7 (main, Sep  7 2022, 15:22:19) [GCC 9.4.0] 064bit on linux
>
> default: 190359856752053127312676546256227168338472159449511832371070549056562920816076745060533362243045799043492106313588416013686785864748509740443321063342671014033379311055519472484045815808.000
> little: 190359856752053127312676546256227168338472159449511832371070549056562920816076745060533362243045799043492106313588416013686785864748509740443321063342671014033379311055519472484045815808.000
> big: 98.600
> native: 190359856752053127312676546256227168338472159449511832371070549056562920816076745060533362243045799043492106313588416013686785864748509740443321063342671014033379311055519472484045815808.000
>
> Done.
> ```

Might also be useful to check:

- [[SO]: Python struct.pack() behavior (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38003729/4788546)

Comment: Thanks very much everyone! Yeshwin Verma The Programmer, Kenny Ostrom, and especially @CristiFati!